# I'm trying to add an element to an object I previously created but I get an error that property does not exist on type {} javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object, javascript-objects

**I just started learning javascript and I'm trying to add an element to an object I previously created but I get an error that property does not exist.**

I cant seem to find the issue, maybe its a syntax error but i cant seem to see it so maybe someone can help me spot it if thats the case?

This is the object >

```
const restaurant = {
  name: 'Classico Italiano',
  location: 'Via Angelo Tavanti 23, Firenze, Italy',
  categories: ['Italian', 'Pizzeria', 'Vegetarian', 'Organic'],
  starterMenu: ['Focaccia', 'Bruschetta', 'Garlic Bread', 'Caprese Salad'],
  mainMenu: ['Pizza', 'Pasta', 'Risotto'],

  openingHours: {
    thu: {
      open: 12,
      close: 22,
    },
    fri: {
      open: 11,
      close: 23,
    },
    sat: {
      open: 0, // Open 24 hours
      close: 24,
    },
  },
  orderD: function ({
    orderName = 'ANON',
    address = 'ANON',
    time = '00:00',
    order = 'ANON',
  }) {
    console.log(`${orderName} has ordered (${order}) to ${address} at ${time}`);
  },
  orderPizza: function (mainIngredient, ...otheringredients) {
    console.log(mainIngredient);
    console.log(otheringredients);
  },
};
```

Then here I tried to add an element to it.

`restaurant.numOfGuests = 0;`

but then it highlights the element name saying

> Property 'numOfGuests' does not exist on type '{ name: string; location: string; categories: string[]; starterMenu: string[]; mainMenu: string[]; openingHours: { thu: { open: number; close: number; }; fri: { open: number; close: number; }; sat: { open: number; close: number; }; }; orderD: ({ orderName, address, time, order, }: { ...; }) => void; orderPizza: (mai...'.ts(2339)

I tried to ignore it and move on but then when i tried logging the new element to the console

`console.log(numOfGuests);`

It gave me this error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: numOfGuests is not defined

Comment: It appears you're using type script? Do you mean to? It may be better to learn one thing at a time, javascript and then typescript.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't appear that you have set the `numOfGuests` property, which is important if your code is TypeScript (as opposed to JavaScript). All you have to do is set it as in the following code. Then, you can reference it in any other code as needed. See [Object Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html) for more information.

```js
const restaurant = {
  name: 'Classico Italiano',
  location: 'Via Angelo Tavanti 23, Firenze, Italy',
  categories: ['Italian', 'Pizzeria', 'Vegetarian', 'Organic'],
  starterMenu: ['Focaccia', 'Bruschetta', 'Garlic Bread', 'Caprese Salad'],
  mainMenu: ['Pizza', 'Pasta', 'Risotto'],
  numOfGuests: 20,

  openingHours: {
    thu: {
      open: 12,
      close: 22,
    },
    fri: {
      open: 11,
      close: 23,
    },
    sat: {
      open: 0, // Open 24 hours
      close: 24,
    },
  },
  orderD: function({
    orderName = 'ANON',
    address = 'ANON',
    time = '00:00',
    order = 'ANON',
  }) {
    console.log(`${orderName} has ordered (${order}) to ${address} at ${time}`);
  },
  orderPizza: function(mainIngredient, ...otheringredients) {
    console.log(mainIngredient);
    console.log(otheringredients);
  },
};
console.log(restaurant);
```

If you're using JavaScript, you shouldn't get the error. See the following code snippet as an example:

```js
const restaurant = {
  name: "Classico Italiano",
  location: "Via Angelo Tavanti 23, Firenze, Italy",
  categories: ["Italian", "Pizzeria", "Vegetarian", "Organic"],
  starterMenu: ["Focaccia", "Bruschetta", "Garlic Bread", "Caprese Salad"],
  mainMenu: ["Pizza", "Pasta", "Risotto"],

  openingHours: {
    thu: {
      open: 12,
      close: 22
    },
    fri: {
      open: 11,
      close: 23
    },
    sat: {
      open: 0, // Open 24 hours
      close: 24
    }
  },
  orderD: function({
    orderName = "ANON",
    address = "ANON",
    time = "00:00",
    order = "ANON"
  }) {
    console.log(`${orderName} has ordered (${order}) to ${address} at ${time}`);
  },
  orderPizza: function(mainIngredient, ...otheringredients) {
    console.log(mainIngredient);
    console.log(otheringredients);
  }
};
restaurant.numOfGuests = 20;
console.log(restaurant);
```

Comment: The course im following they didnt do it that way, they just added the item later on without setting it in the object 
I could've done that but I wanna know what happened and how to fix it

Comment: That error is because you're using typescript and typescript wants to know exactly what fields your object has. You can read more about it here https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-from-scratch.html

Comment: Yeah, if you're using TypeScript, you must provide typings as @nlta stated. If using JavaScript, you shouldn't get the error. I'll update my answer to demonstrate this.